# How to reference an x86/x64/ARM class library (not an AnyCPU class library) in WinRT

Tags: sqlite, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

In mvvmcross, I've got a plugin class library which references SQLite for WinRT.

Because of this, I can't build that class library as AnyCPU - instead, I have to reference it as x86, x64 or Any CPU.

This means that new client applications can't just reference a single DLL, but instead individual configurations must reference different input assemblies. Currently I'm doing this by manually editing the .csproj file using conditions.

However, this is a bit error prone (and a bit hard to explain!)

Is there any 'easy' way (1 click way) for client applications to reference the x86/x64/ARM class library trio so that MSBuild then picks the right version at runtime?

Comment: I asked [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a9ac0bdb-a439-4a36-870d-b32d0403e354/#a9ac0bdb-a439-4a36-870d-b32d0403e354) on MSDN forums and got no good answer yet. You can always upvote and comment there in hopes that someone at Microsoft looks at it again.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not rely on perfect performance, you might switch to C# SQLite, which is purely managed (Any CPU), so that your class libraries and executable can be set as Any CPU.

Alternatively, you might use Dependency Injection or MEF to inject the assemblies/types of correct bitness at runtime, and in this way at compile time you always work against an interface (which is bitness independent).

As far as I know, MSBuild cannot automatically handle bitness in the way you wanted.